# \left and \right broken

Tags: math-mode, unicode-math

Sorry for the lame question. `\left` and `\right` are not resulting in upsizing of parentheses all through my document, and I don’t know what’s breaking them
[image: problem]

The code for the bottom equaition is as follows:

```
\begin{equation}
\frac{1}{λ} = R_H \left(\frac{1}{n_f^2} - \frac{1}{n_i^2}\right)
\label{eqn:rydberg relation}
\end{equation}
```

I am using

```
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{tikz}
...
```

with MacTeX. I’ve wasted a lot of time trying to figure out why this isn’t working. What could be the cause? How should I start to debug it?

---

**Solution:**

Don’t begin an abstract with `\abstract`. Use `\begin{abstract} ... \end{abstract}`. The former is not delimited and will make the whole document the abstract.

(I had always thought `\abstract` was similar to `\section{Title}`.)

Comment: To find the cause and to start to debug make a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) and add it to your question.

Comment: I tried with XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX and got the expected size (which is too large, by the way, because of the subscript f; `\bigg` size would be better).

Comment: The problem is ‘fixed’ when I delete my abstract. I still don’t know why removing that would affect the very end of the document (from which the screenshot was taken). Is there anything wrong with starting the abstract with `\abstract`?

Comment: (I should add that the problem persists even when the abstract is empty…)

Comment: Ah. I discovered that using `\begin{abstract} ... \end{abstract}` works, but `\abstract` breaks things. (Why…?)

Comment: @egreg Using `\bigg` breaks more things. `\bigg(abc` is rendered as “ (⌧abc” … (yes, that’s a crossed box) Is that an unrelated font problem? :(

Comment: `\abstract` is wrong and will put the entire document in to the abstract as there is no `\end{abstract}` but it is unlikely to affect `\left` `\right`. But whatever the problem is it is in the part of the document you showed as `....` so no one can really help you. the posted example should make it possible for people to replicate the problem and debug it.

Comment: Please do not put a solution into the question, it makes a mess of the site structure.  You can post an answer to your own question.  (However as I commented above it seems rather unlikely that the error with `\abstract` is related to the delimiters.)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes… I feel like this question should be removed. I can’t post an answer to it, it’s on hold. I was just desperate about the problem and gave up too soon. The question isn’t helpful for others.